# Date as folder name

Tags: c#, datetime, directory, filenames

Fast one, why this code isnt working for me:

```
Directory.CreateDirectory(DateTime.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy"));
```

Erorr:

```
Error   1   An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'System.DateTime.ToString(string)'    Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\WindowsFormsApplication1\WindowsFormsApplication1\Form1.cs    83  39  WindowsFormsApplication1
```

What is wrong? And if I would like to have folders name as "This is folder of" and then add todays date, how should it look?

Comment: Try the simpler expression `DateTime.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy")` - what happens?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Maybe you mean:

```
Directory.CreateDirectory(DateTime.Now.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy"));
```

Answer (score 5):

> What is wrong?

`ToString` is an *instance* method not a static one, therefore you can't call it on `DateTime` class directly - you need to call it on an *instance* of the `DateTime` class.

> And if I would like to have folders name as "This is folder of" and then add todays date, how should it look?

You can use the `Now`/`UtcNow` property of the `DateTime` class which would give you the current time instance e.g.

```
DateTime.UtcNow.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy");
```

Comment: +1. for detailed comments. Side note: Using "yyyy-MM-dd" format makes sorting folders by name much more reasonable...

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov +1 back as that's a fair point. I was thinking of UTC format in my head when I posted the answer but because the OP has specifically mentioned `dd-MM-yyyy` I wanted to give a solution that would work in the way they wanted. However, as you say for sorting purposes UTC date format would be better.

Answer (score 4):

```
Directory.CreateDirectory(DateTime.Now.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy"));
```